# obtener los hijos de un ul en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `ul` con varios `li` como hijos a los cuales si le hacemos click llaman a una funcion que debería obtener las referencias a los hijos del `li` al que se le hizo click en este caso un `h2` y un `p`.

La función no tiene problema en los `li` que son de índice par pero en los que son impares el `console.log` devuelve `null`.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

console.log(ul);
 

function selection(item){
    const selectedLi = ul.children[item];

    const h2 = selectedLi.querySelector("h2");

    const p = selectedLi.querySelector("p");

    console.log(item);

    console.log(h2);

    console.log(p);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>FAQ</h1>

  <ul>

    <li onclick="selection(0)">
      <h2>How many team members can I invite?</h2>
      <p>
        You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
        team members for the Premium plan.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>

    <li onclick="selection(1)">
      <h2>What is the maximum file upload size</h2>
      <p>
        No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>

    <li onclick="selection(2)">
      <h2>How do I reset my password?</h2>
      <p>
        Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.
        A reset link will be emailed to you.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>

    <li onclick="selection(3)">
      <h2>Can I cancel my subscription?</h2>
      <p>
        Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>

    <li onclick="selection(4)">
      <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
      <p>
        Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>

    <li onclick="selection(5)">
      <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
      <p>
        Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>
    
    <li onclick="selection(6)">
      <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
      <p>
        Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>
    
    <li onclick="selection(7)">
      <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
      <p>
        Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
      </p>
    </li>

    <hr>
    
  </ul>

</main>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Para la próxima escribe el código como texto en la pregunta. Puedes dejar un link a otro sitio, pero no que tu pregunta dependa únicamente de él. Por más que te respondan igual. La pregunta puede terminar cerradas.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pasas como argumento "this" en vez del número no vas a tener problema.

Nota: Tu error está en unas etiquetas `<hr>` que tienes por ahí dentro

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
console.log(ul);
 

function selection(item){

 const h2 = item.querySelector("h2");
 const p = item.querySelector("p");

    console.log(item);
    console.log(h2);
    console.log(p);

}
```

```html
      <ul>

        <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>How many team members can I invite?</h2>
          <p>
            You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on
            team members for the Premium plan.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>

        <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>What is the maximum file upload size</h2>
          <p>
            No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>

        <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>How do I reset my password?</h2>
          <p>
            Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.
            A reset link will be emailed to you.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>

        <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>Can I cancel my subscription?</h2>
          <p>
            Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>

        <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
          <p>
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>

              <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
          <p>
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>
        
                      <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
          <p>
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>
        
                      <li onclick="selection(this)">
          <h2>Do you provide additional support</h2>
          <p>
            Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.
          </p>
        </li>

        <hr>
        
      </ul>
```

Comment: Muchar gracias por tu respuesta, cuando vuelva del trabajo voy a probar

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que lo hr son también hijos de ul (algo incorrecto en HTML, hr no puede ser hijode ul). Mete los hr dentro de cada li y todo funcionará correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta voy a probarlo.

Comment: Creo que si está respondida: indico el error y la forma de solucionarlo, al menos es lo que he tratado de hacer.